# Drupal 7: Custom content types become un-editable and do not output correctly

Tags: users

I've had the following problem a few times and can't find a satisfactory answer to it anywhere.

- I create a new content type
- add content for this new type
- then, when the system displays the finished content after save, all of the new fields are missing (yes I made sure they were set to 'display' in the manage display tab)
- on editing this new node, none of the fields display, all I get is the node title field and the tabbed options (eg comments, create version, menus etc)

I've read that this is caused by a permission problem. That sounded good, so I checked the permissions after creating the new content type and sure enough, there were no boxes checked for the new content type.

I checked all of the boxes for the admin role for the content type and still nothing. I've rebuilt the permissions and cleared the cache. Still nothing.

Comment: Do you have any other modules installed?  I wonder if one of the other modules may be doing something with the form to interfere with the saving of the information.

Comment: Yes it looks like that a module is causing it. Details to follow...Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've worked out that if I disable Organic groups > Field access module then it starts working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dylan - have you looked here?  http://drupal.org/node/1029230

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I will have a good look through this when I get a chance.